# Composition vs inheritance for a heading (H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6) component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working to create a Base Heading Component which is used by the H1, H2, H3 components.

Here's what I have so far:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import H1 from './H1';
import H2 from './H2';
import H3 from './H3';


class Heading extends React.Component {
  static H1 = H1;
  static H2 = H2;
  static H3 = H3;
}

export default Heading;
```

**Base Component**
/src/components/Heading/Base.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const Container = styled.div`
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.marginBottom}px;
  ${({ centered }) => centered && `
    text-align: center;
  `}
`;

class Base extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {
      children,
      centered,
      marginBottom
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container
        centered={centered}
        marginBottom={marginBottom}
      >
        {children}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  centered: PropTypes.bool,
  marginBottom: PropTypes.number,
};

export default Base;
```

Now I am trying to use the Base component as part of H1, H2, H3 since all of them will have the same shared props (centered, children, marginBottom and the same basic stylings like font-family).

/src/components/Heading/H3.js

How in H3.js can I inherit the default props from the Base but then customize H3 with unique h3 styles? And is inheritance the right way to accomplish this?

In my page I would then call the H3 component like so:

```
<Heading.H3 centered>Hello World </Heading.H3>
```

Comment: Depending on whether you'd want to incorporate a library, Material-UI might not be a bad idea for this. They have a `Typography` component that seems to accomplish what you're looking for: https://material-ui.com/api/typography/.

Comment: @CarlEdwards thanks for pointing this out but need to avoid using a library

Comment: Ah gotcha. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sounds like you want a higher order component?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's part of my question, so many options, is a HOC the right way to go? not inheritance or extending?

Comment: I prefer composition over inheritance, but that’s an opinion. “The right way to go” is opinionated.

Comment: @evolutionxbox would you be able to show an example of composition accomplishing the H3.js goal? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to share the propType definitions or actually trying to 'inherit' the values? Can you do a quick code sandbox of how it should work?

Comment: inherit - meaning H1, H2, H3, all inherit the options for centered and marginBottom. Am I understanding this correctly?